# Storm best topology design patterns for I/O tasks

Tags: asynchronous, io, apache-storm

So, I have a framework where the input is a `Kafka` queue of `Tweet` documents. My topology needs to read it and hit three different **external** APIs.

I need a way to make sure all three are done before moving forward. I don't think a `BatchBolt` is a good solution, is it? Can anybody help with this?

**Edit** / **Clarification**

The three API hits need to return the results. I would need to process these responses before the document is passed over to the next `bolt`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right. You have kafka spout emmiting messages. And each message need to be delivered in three different systems.
This could be easely done configuring topology.

```
TopologyBuilder topologyBuilder = new TopologyBuilder ();
topologyBuilder.setSpout("Generator", spout, 1);
topologyBuilder.setBolt("External1", bolt1, 1).localOrShuffleGrouping("Generator");
topologyBuilder.setBolt("External2", bolt2, 1).localOrShuffleGrouping("Generator");
topologyBuilder.setBolt("External3", bolt3, 1).localOrShuffleGrouping("Generator");
```

In this simple example 3 different bolt connected to 1 kafka spout. When spout emit message it goes to all three bolts same time. If one of the bolts don't acknoledge tuple it will fail, and reemited to all of these bolts.

Comment: Aah, no. All of them need to hit an external API and return the result before being emitted to the next bolt.

Comment: So you need to call these 3 API sequentialy?

Comment: Not sequentially, but I would need the results from all three before proceeding for the next step.